# how to convert kruti dev to unicode in php

Tags: php

I want to convert kruti dev (Indian language) to unicode. There is this site - http://rajbhasha.net/drupal514/UniKrutidev+Converter which converts krutidev to unicode but this is done in javascript. I want to do it in php, can someone help.

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that Kruti Dev is not an encoding but a font based on non-standardized character mappings? I.e. it just maps the character that should be "A" to an Indian character, "B" to another one etc? In that case there's no standardized tool to convert that, since it's not a standard. You have to write your own code mapping each "wrong" character to the right Unicode character.

Comment: @deceze that must be why i couldn't find the name of the encoding.

Comment: Hello @Sajal, did you get success to solve your problem ? I have also have same issue, let me knwo if you can help me, thanks

Comment: @ s4suryapal: what is your req. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have to do is not an *encoding conversion* but a custom *character mapping*.

In an encoding a specific *byte* or *byte sequence* stands for a specific *character*. The *font* then visualizes this character. For example, in ASCII the byte `x41` stands for the character "A", and different fonts have different *shapes* to display this "A" visibly on screen.

In the case of Kruti Dev, apparently at the time it came into being, there was no encoding for Indian languages; i.e. there was no particular byte specified that should represent "व" in any system in use at the time. What the creators of Kruti Dev did was simply redefine the shape of a letter. The bytes still said the letter was "A", the operating system still thought it was handling the letter "A", but the font contained the shape of "व" for visual display.

So there's no *encoding* conversion you can do here, since the underlying encoding is being abused in non-standard ways to begin with. What you need to do is to map latin letters to actually specified Indian letters. You need to substitute every "A" for "व" (just an example, no idea about the actual mapping).

Comment: thanks mate. yeah i understand i will have to go for character mapping. The link you provided, i already googled it out but wasn't sure how to us it. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

```
$str = iconv($srcencoding, $destencoding, $str);
```

Comment: what wrong with the utf8_encode() ?
please elaborate...

Comment: @Rajeev It converts Latin-1 encoded strings to UTF-8. It has absolutely nothing to do with Indian characters and is of no use there.

Comment: thanks guys for your comments. Yes krutidev is a hindi language font. Let me show how it looks : 
fot; dqekj 'kkg - this is krutidev font in copied from excel
विजय कुमार शाह - this is equivalent hindi language

@Orangepill: i checked out iconv but i am not sure how to use it. can you please help with above details provided.
Thanks

Comment: @SajalDas deceze has the correct answer.