# How to convert KrutiDev font to Unicode Vice Versa in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

Can we convert Krutidev font in Unicode via any logical code or Is mapping is only way to convert.
Please suggest if any logical or mapping or other way to this conversion.

Thanks,

Comment: CHeck out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482396/how-to-convert-kruti-dev-to-unicode-in-php   I'm not going to close this as a dupe because of the language difference.

Comment: Yes, I need in java.  the inner link of that link that you have share it's not working..giving 404 ERROR and this is also  php based.